# Multiple request/response in socket programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

In multithreaded server which assigns new client to a new thread, I want to device a pattern which will handle multiple request/acknowledgment for a client.

Please see the operation sequence below (Once client is connected)

1. Client sends request to get status of particular file on server
2. Server sends data in response to client.
3. Client decides some action based on server response
4. Client may send another request, say to fetch a file
5. Server sends file to client

I'm thinking about a model where request/response is based on "ACTION_STRINGS". i.e. one party sends particular "ACTION_STRING" and then the data so that other party can understand different actions (like getting status of file or fetching file) and work based on that action.

The question here is, is this good model to work upon? Suggest if improvements are possible. Suggest if other model is better than this.

Comment: It not only common, but _very_ common. In fact that's the way that HTTP works: The client send a request, the server sends a response, the client sends another request, the server another response, etc.

Comment: that's a design question. Your protocol is similar to http, with ACTION_STRINGS acting like verbs (`GET`, `PUT`, `POST`) in http, and the connection in keep-alive mode. Perhaps you could use http?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's correct, but question was about how to implement it. I suggested ACTION_STRINGS

Comment: @didierc Hmmm that makes sense. But I can't use http. Have to device my own protocol. Thanks.

Comment: webdav-like protocols are sometimes used for a "disk in the cloud" systems.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Can you please elaborate your comment in the context of the question?

Comment: you could use [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) (an extension of http) or its variation as a protocol for your application if mere http is not enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing this is very simple.

The clients sends its verb, or action, which should contain a terminator (`"\r\n"` is the most common in the Internet world).

The server then reads the request (or action) from the client. It can either read until the terminator and then decide if more is needed depending on the action, or read until a final terminator (in HTTP this is an empty line, i.e. `"\r\n"` directly followed by another `"\r\n"`). Then the server performs the action requested and optionally sends a response.

The client meanwhile, waits for the response from the server. It then reads all of the response and does something with the data. For the response, since you might send binary data, you can't have a fixed terminator as that might actually be embedded in the binary data, so you need to send the length of the data before the actual data.

---

As your protocol seems to be very much alike HTTP, I suggest you start from HTTP and extend it to add whatever other verbs you need. For example, you could use the HTTP `GET` request to get a file, and add an `INFO` request to get information about a file.

Comment: Is keep-alive mode by default or I'll have to set it, in case I use multiple requests in same sessions.

Comment: @DivyangPatel You don't have to keep the _exact_ same model as HTTP, just use the part of it that you need as base, then extend and modify the part that need to be extended and modified. This of course includes things like persistent connections and the like. Of just use HTTP as inspiration while making up your own protocol.

Comment: @DivyangPatel: yes. Unless you specify `Connection: close` in the request header, the server will keep the connection in http/1.1